# Is there any software to batch align copies of a pictures?

Tags: image-alignment, auto-alignment

Are there any software to batch-align copies of a picture so that they are in same position ? These picture were clicked with a handheld camera.

They are all landscape shots taken at different parts of the season from the same location.  This is a sample of one of the images.

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by in the same position. Are they multiple shots of the same scene?

Comment: A quick search of this site would have turned up several relevant existing questions with plenty of good answers.

Comment: @mattdm Thnx for the reference. Didn't know the correct keywords to search for.Sorry for not being so clear. Hugo...they are the multiple shots of the same scene taken at different seasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photoshop can align layers in the way that you seek.

1. Load each image into a single photoshop document as a different layer
2. Select all the layers by using shift-click.
3. Go under "edit" and choose "Auto Align Layers".
4. You will then be presented with a dialogue box, in your case I suspect "auto" will work just fine.

Depending on how different each image is, however, the auto align may not do a very good job and you may have to do it by hand yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You could try with [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/).

It's largely intended for aligning shots to make a panorama, so it may or may not be useful depending on your intended final output. If you're wanting to get aligned overlapping images, then you'll want the intermediate TIFFs it produces just before merging. They'll be aligned, warped to the same viewpoint, and cropped to your chosen framing.

There's a variety of different methods for selecting the matching points (you may have to check them manually) between frames. The auto methods assume fairly similar features, so may get confused if the images change a lot between seasons.

And you can optimise for various camera parameters, even position, so I think it should allow for slight variations in where you were standing for the shots. But the more parameters you're optimising over, the bigger the chance of failure. It can get pretty complicated to work out position and orientation parameters at once, especially if some of your features don't quite match up.